# Regex Matching on Regex101 but not matching with preg_match or preg_match_all php functions

Tags: php, regex

```
$regex = "/<[^>]+>\s(.*)\s+(?=<[^>]+pt10 pb5">)/i";

$str = "</div>
         Quick and delicious appetizer with mince and bread for your feast menu. You can serve these mouth watering strips as a snack with noon tea.
         <div class="pt10 pb5">";
```

tested on regex101 and regexr and working fine on both but not with php functions and I also tried to find any character that I need to escape but not found anything. 
thanx in advance for help

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you expect this code to do? It only defines two variables

Comment: I am trying to match the paragraph between closing div and div at the end containing pt10 pt5 classes

Comment: I am explained it that with preg_match_all and Preg_match php functions this regex is not working but working fine when tested on regex101

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew can you please point me out where the hell is this question got answered

Comment: @NaeemAkhtar The link is on top, under your post headline. Just fix the syntax issues, and the only thing you need is adding `s` modifier. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/0pxrKZ).

Comment: thanx @Wiktor Stribiżew my issue is resolved thanx again